Column of duplicated pixels down the middle of external display after resuming from sleep
My 16-inch 2023 MacBook Pro M3 Max sometimes (maybe 5% of the time) shows a column of pixels down the middle of my external monitor(s) duplicated after resuming from sleep. I'm not sure how to describe the issue to search it online, so here's a video: https://i.imgur.com/59DYXAe.mp4
The laptop is closed ("clamshell mode") and it usually happens on the primary external display, though sometimes on both. Both displays are identical (LG 27GN800) connected via HDMI to an iVANKY FusionDock 1 Pro, though this also happened when connected with an Anker dock.
This happened with macOS 14, but is still happening with macOS 15. When it does, I can resolve it by turning the monitor off and back on, but I'm getting really tired of it. Has anyone seen this before, have ideas of where the problem could be, or even know what other terms I should try searching for? This is my first Mac after years of troubleshooting Windows and Linux, so I'm out of ideas!
